# Items Compare Page ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create an items compare page just like this:
http://www.autotrader.com/fyc/compare.jsp?sownerid=855612&end_year=2014&start_year=1981&keywordsfyc=&search_type=both&scarid=326877152&distance=10&default_sort=priceDESC&address=11413&sort_type=priceDESC&firstRecord=1&num_records=25&seller_type=b&keywords_display=&compare=305557040&compare=319902555&compare=337325579

(this is a compare page from autotraders.com)

I have been searching fourms for a week now , trying all possible solutions, some say use GridView, some say use ListView, I tried many things, custom div css as well, but couldn't do it.
Basically, I want to show vertical rows (side by side rows) instead of default horizontal rows.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can make use of `Repeater` control or `DataList` control.

More on [Repeater](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/repeater-controls-in-Asp-Net/) or [DataList](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23559/Working-with-the-DataList-Control)

> i would personally go for `Repeater` .
>
> Example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ExampleRepeater" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCategory" Text='<%# Eval("YouColumnName") %>' > </asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% #Eval("YourImageColumn %>'></asp:ImageButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOtherInfo" Text='<%# Eval("YouColumnName") %>' > </asp:Label>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thank for the reply... But the example shows horizontal rows... what I need is vertical rows... and the headers shows at the left horizontally...

Comment: in a repeater control you can render the html the way you want it. also mark the answer as useful so that it mite help others.

Comment: I'll appreciate it if you have an example.

Comment: check a sample...and tweak it as per your requirement. Repeater i believe would be best in your scenario.

Comment: Thnaks... I just tried it... it is ok... but How can I display the column names only one time on the left and the rows side-by-side

Comment: thats exactly the above repeater example will do. if you notice it has on <tr> and three <td>. So the first <td> will act like your header and the other two <td> will act like images or labels or whatever you wanna set. u can include more <td> if you want. more <td> means more rows side by side. Also, mark the answer as usefull so that it will help others too.

Comment: Thanks a million ... Repeater With Table Design Worked.... Very straight Forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525914/how-to-make-a-comparison-html-table-using-asp-repeater-data-rotation) to solve your problem. It works i checked it. And use [this article](http://www.webanddesigners.com/50-product-comparison-tables-in-web-design/) to designe your comparison table

Comment: Thanks for the answer.... But I have the same problem... I can't convert all columns to nvarchar coz they are in different formats and it contains images as well :-(

Comment: You could create some properties such as Data, Image and other, and use it in the table specifically. You can use their as <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# ImageUrl%>' />

Comment: Thanks, I used Table design